# TypeConverter is not called for property value when the value is written as a XAML element

Tags: wpf, xaml, typeconverter, xamlreader

Suppose that I have a property `MyProperty` of type `MyType` in a class `MyClass`. I want to use XAML to assign it some complex value of another type (let's take `String`, for example). So, I create `MyTypeConverter` which can convert from `String` to `MyType` and apply `[TypeConverter(typeof(MyTypeConverter))]` to the `MyClass` class.

The following code works fine (i.e. invokes MyTypeConverter.ConvertFrom):

```
<MyClass.MyProperty>
    text
</MyClass.MyProperty>
```

But as soon as I change the property value to a XAML elemet, the TypeConverter is no longer being invoked which results in a conversion exception.

```
<MyClass.Property>
    <sys:String>text</sys:String>
</MyClass.Property>
```

How can I implement conversion for the values defined as XAML elements?

Comment: This behaviour seems absolutely logical to me, you cannot *explicitly* assign a string object to a property of a different type.

Comment: `TypeConverter` can convert and is used to convert from any type. Why should it be restrained to conversion from string literals only (and bindings)?

Comment: What I want is to not need to explicitly wrap the XAML elements in adapters every time.

Comment: For literals and bindings the type is not explicitly set. Type conversion is implicit so it makes sense that it only applies to implciitly typed values without overriding explicit ones. (Also one usually only converts from and to strings, so haivng this limitation should not really matter)

Comment: Ok. I looked at the TypeConverter implementations and they really only deal with strings. I wonder why did they decided to create and use the powerful TypeConverter system with all its CanConvertFrom/CanConvertTo, when all that they actually needed and used was a pair of FromString/ToString methods (Serialize/Deserialize).  BTW, the implicit conversion operators don't work too. Looks like I've hit the dead end.

Comment: I thought/you said the first snippet worked?

Comment: The snuppets are simplified. My real values are complex types. I just wanted to avoid wrapping each collection value in a converter: `<MyClass><MyConverter><Value .../></MyConverter><MyConverter><Value .../></MyConverter><MyConverter><Value .../></MyConverter></MyClass>`